# How do I write tests for facebook graph api in my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, tdd

I'm using rails 3 and experimenting with the facebook graph api. I'm trying to do things in a TDD/BDD way but I'm not sure how to test my calls to the api. Do I simply wrap the facebook api methods into stubs and return mock objects?

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually faced with a similar problem.  I'm looking at https://github.com/mislav/fakeweb as a way of mocking out http responses.  Haven't used it for real yet, but based on my preliminary experiments I think it'll work for my purposes.   Maybe it'll work for yours too.

Answer (score 0):

i've recently released a utility to help with this. it's a standalone implementation of Facebook's FQL and Graph API that you can run on your development machine.

http://code.google.com/p/mockfacebook/